# Gmpy documentation anywhere?

Tags: python, gmp

I installed gmpy-1.11rc1.win32-py2.6.exe, but can't figure out how to use it, I can see some exported functions like mpz, mpq, mpf, etc., but how do I call a function like mpz_probab_prime_p() in GNU MP C library?

I looked at gmpy on [Google Code](http://code.google.com/p/gmpy/source/browse/trunk/src/?r=198), but still can't figure out. I couldn't find gmpy's documentation anywhere either. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can find the docs [here](http://code.google.com/p/gmpy/source/browse/trunk/doc/gmpydoc.txt).

Comment: [A link should never be the only piece of information in your answer](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259/130885)  How do you call a function like `mpz_probab_prime_p()`?

Comment: This link is outdated, Google Code has been deprecated

Answer (score 4):

For now the `txt` file jbochi mentions is all there is -- and unfortunately it's not structured in the terms the OP requires, i.e., showing what underlying GMP functions are used in each `gmpy`-exposed function or method.  If you're a GMP expert you can search the gmpy code [here](http://code.google.com/p/gmpy/source/browse/#svn/trunk/src) -- specifically in [this file](http://code.google.com/p/gmpy/source/browse/trunk/src/gmpy_mpz.c), which implements MPZ functionality, you'll see the call you seek at line 1538 (within the `is_prime` function/method).

I did recently acquire site `gmpy.org` with the idea of developing better online docs, but haven't gotten started yet (of course I could equally well use the wiki pages at gmpy's google code hosting site) -- as always in open source, volunteers are welcome!-)

Answer (score 3):

[GMPY2 documentation is now on ReadTheDocs](https://gmpy2.readthedocs.org/). There are installation instructions and an API reference.

Answer (score 1):

This may be useful as well:

```
>>> import(gmpy)
>>> help(gmpy)
```

Comment: in python 2.7 "import gmpy"